# falta de referencia, como la encuentro?

Tags: c#, referencias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy creando un macro para que se graben las acciones del teclado, mouse y quiero poder grabarlas, intente usar esta referencia pero cuando voy a pry > agregar referencia > ensamblados> no me aparece ninguna que se llame Recording o un dll que se llame de esa manera... ya lo consulte con chatgpt pero solo me dice que agregue la referencia pero no puedo. ayuda!

Comment: Y de donde es que salen esos paquetes??? porque algun using tenes que agregar para usar eso....

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta, e insertar el código donde te muestra el error,  y el espacio de nombres?

Comment: Ya intentaste con Ctrl + . Esa combinación de teclas te muestra sugerencias, incluso de  paquetes que no tienes instalados